# How to access certain part of a JSON?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to access the text "Passion" in the following code, but I can't figure out how. Right now I can only get

```
{"parts": [{"text": "Passion"]}
```

Can anyone tell me what to do next? Thanks!

```
$test = 
'{
    "event":
    {
        "response":"{\"parts\": [{\"text\": \"Passion\"]}"
    },
    "event_source":"server"
}';

$jarray = json_decode($test, true);
echo $jarray['event']['response'];
```

Comment: json seems to be invalid here, so it can't get parsed :- `"{\"parts\": [{\"text\": \"Passion\"]}"` . you can check here:- https://jsonlint.com/  . check my example link:- https://3v4l.org/vlMFA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you json data is invalid here:-

```
"{\"parts\": [{\"text\": \"Passion\"]}" 
//----------------------------------^ one } needed before ]
```

After correcting the input do like below:

```
<?php

$test = 
'{
    "event":
    {
        "response":"{\"parts\": [{\"text\": \"Passion\"}]}"
    },
    "event_source":"server"
}';

$jarray = json_decode($test, true);

print_r($jarray);

$response = json_decode($jarray['event']['response'], true);

echo $response['parts'][0]['text'];
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/dmPDE

Comment: Here is my new question. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56520493/how-to-access-certain-part-of-a-nested-json?answertab=votes#tab-top